# Data in JSON file not showing in html

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, html

I'm using AngularJS to load data to my html file and my local server is wamp server. But records in JSON file not loading to index.html page.

Index.html :

```
<head>
    <meta charset = "UTF-8">
    <title>AngularJS | $http Service</title>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.5/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src = "controller.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app = "mainApp">
    <div ng-controller = "people">
        <ul>
            <h2>Names and Age of Programmers in Colombo</h2>
            <li ng-repeat = "person in persons">
                {{ person.name + ' : ' + person.age }}
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
```

Controller.js :

```
var app = angular.module('mainApp', []); 
app.controller('people', function($scope, $http) {
  $http.get('http://localhost/angular/Tut16_httpService/database.json').success (function(response) {
    $scope.persons = response.records;
  }); 
});
```

database.json :

```
{
"records": [
    {
        "Name":"Mehul",
        "Age":"18"
    },
    {
        "Name":"Jai",
        "Age":"24"
    },
    {
        "Name":"Alex",
        "Age":"27"
    },
    {
        "Name":"Rahul",
        "Age":"30"
    }
] 
}
```

Output is : 
[image]

Any Help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Property name should be as same as json file.

Convert this

```
{{ person.name + ' : ' + person.age }}
```

to this

```
{{ person.Name + ' : ' + person.Age }}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<div ng-controller = "people">
        <ul>
            <h2>Names and Age of Programmers in Colombo</h2>
            <li ng-repeat = "person in persons.records">
                {{ person.Name + ' : ' + person.Age }}
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

plunker :- https://plnkr.co/edit/mRyRnovs2zpk5pMNjbaW?p=preview

Good Luck !! Simple Mistake Buddy Watch it :-) !!